# How to set delimiters like "|,|" in python/pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I want to import a txt dataset into pandas.
The dataset is like:

|2014|,|H0AK00097|,|N00032846|,|John Cox (R)|,|R|,|AK01|,|    |,| |,|Y|,|C|,|RL|,| |
|2014|,|H0AL02087|,|N00030768|,|Martha Roby (R)|,|R|,|AL02|,|AL02|,|Y|,|Y|,|I|,|RW|,| |

The delimiters are "|,|', or just '|" at the start and end of a row.
I tried several ways to set delimiters in pd.read_csv() function, but all failed.
How to set this parameter?

I tried

```
ind=pd.read_csv('indivs14.txt',sep=',', header=None, engine='python',error_bad_lines=False)
```

But the outcome is incorrect.

Comment: Can the character | be part of a value? If not, just preprocess that hideous file and throw these characters out. Then you have a normal CSV.

Comment: You can also strip the starting and trailing pipe character from each individual cell after reading the data; just be aware that each cell will automatically be of string type.

Comment: Maybe with a regex?

Answer (score 0):

The following may work: it reads the CSV with normal comma separators, then strips the `|` on the sides of each cell:

```
df = pd.read_csv('bab.txt', header=None).applymap(lambda s: s.strip('|'))
```

Result:

```
     0          1          2                3  4     5     6  7  8  9   10 11
0  2014  H0AK00097  N00032846     John Cox (R)  R  AK01           Y  C  RL
1  2014  H0AL02087  N00030768  Martha Roby (R)  R  AL02  AL02  Y  Y  I  RW
```

Caveats:

- extra `|`s that are part of the actual cell are also stripped
- all columns will be of string type (with the given example data, only for the first column may this be a problem). No integers, floats or datetimes; you'd have to do any conversions yourself.

Comment: Great, thanks! But just now I found some names with a comma inside. I'll try to replace |,| with another delimiter in the text file first. Thanks again!

Comment: @Canvas See my other answer, where names with a comma inside are no problem, *because* they are "quoted" with the pipe character, thus the internal commas are safe.

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility, depending on how the data should be interpreted, is to interpret the pipe character as a quote character (and I think this is the actual format of the input file). Then it's simply:

```
df = pd.read_csv('bab.txt', quotechar="|", header=None)
```

and the result

```
     0          1          2                3  4     5     6  7  8  9   10 11
0  2014  H0AK00097  N00032846     John Cox (R)  R  AK01           Y  C  RL
1  2014  H0AL02087  N00030768  Martha Roby (R)  R  AL02  AL02  Y  Y  I  RW
```

Comment: this is a nice solution!

Comment: Great! Perfectly solved. But I cannot vote up currently...Thank you so much!

Comment: @Canvas You can probably mark it as solved (accepted answer) though, if you want to.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work with the example you provided:

```
ind = pd.read_csv('indivs14.txt',sep=',', header=None, engine='python',error_bad_lines=False)
ind.replace({'\|': ''}, regex=True, inplace=True)
```

However this should not be used if the character '|' is part of some values (i.e., should not be removed) as mentioned by @timgeb in the comments.